# Analitic solution to ${df(x)\over{dx}} + {1\over2} f^2 (x) = ax^2 +bx + c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

What is the analytic solution to the following differential equation? $${df(x)\over{dx}} + {1\over2} f^2 (x) = ax^2 +bx + c$$

I know that this is a nonlinear nonhomogeneous first-order ODE. However, I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Is this a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia's page, I just learned that it is possible to convert Riccatti equation to a second order linear DE.

Let $u$ be a solution of the following the second order linear DE:
$$u''-\frac{1}{2}(ax^2+bx+c)u=0.\tag{*}$$
Then consider $y_p=\frac{2u'}{u}$. By differentiating we have
$$y_p'=\frac{2u''u-2(u')^2}{u^2}=\frac{(ax^2+bx+c)u^2-2(\frac{1}{2}uy_p)^2}{u^2}=(ax^2+bx+c)-\frac{1}{2}y_p^2.$$
Hence, $y_p$ satisfies the Riccatti Equation $y'+\frac{1}{2}y^2=ax^2+bx+c.$

The general solution can be found by the usual procedure for solving Riccatti equation knowing a particular solution.

So all remains is to solve $(*)$ :https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27-%281%2F2%29%28ax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%29y%3D0
I don't know the parabolic cylinder function. I would try to solve $(*)$ by usual series method. I think.

Comment: Thank you Bob, you are correct. I will actually go with the parabolic cylinder function. Thank you very much.

Comment: We need reduction? @LutzLehmann

Comment: The second order equation already has two parameters. As one can cancel a common factor in the quotient for $y$, only one degree of freedom remains. Thus you get already the general solution of the first-order equation.

Comment: The transformation for Riccati with one known solution is to set $y=y_p+\frac1z$, which should result in a linear first-order equation for $z$.

Comment: I felt like an undergradute student in Nkü whose teacher is very angry for my mistake.

Comment: It's ***Riccati***. The Italian word “ricatti” is the plural of “ricatto”, that is, *blackmail*.